# Images Persistence and Lazy Loading Conflict With Dispatch_Async

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, grand-central-dispatch

I am working on a feed reader and i am doing it by parsing rss feeds using nsxmlparser. I also have thumbnail objects that i am taking from the CDATA block.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *storyImageURL = [self getFirstImageUrl:someString];

    NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL URLWithString:storyImageURL];

    NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tempURL];
    thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:tempData];

    });
}
```

I am persisting the images and other tableview objects using archiving and encode and decode methods.

The issue is when i use the above code as it is, it does not persist images while other tableview objects like title and published date do persist. But when i use the above code without  dispatch_async around it, then it starts persisting the images but locks the user interface.

How can i persist the images without locking the user interface?

Kindly do not answer with some library to store and cache images or Apple's lazy loading example. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Based on the answer provided and after watching a lecture by Stanford in iTunes on Multithreading, i have implemented the above code as follow:

```
  NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *storyImageURL = [self getFirstImageUrl:someString];
    NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL URLWithString:storyImageURL];

    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("image downloader", NULL);

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tempURL];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:tempData];
        });
    });
}
```

Logically, everything is correct now but still it didn't work. I am all blocked how to solve this issue.

**UPDATE:**

I am using the Model View Controller Store approach and my store and connection code are defined in separate files. Below is the code where i am using NSKeyedArchiver.

```
- (FeedChannel *) FeedFetcherWithCompletion:(void (^)(FeedChannel *, NSError *))block {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techcrunch.com/feed/"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    FeedChannel *channel = [[FeedChannel alloc] init];

    TheConnection *connection = [[TheConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req];

    NSString *pathOfCache = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    pathOfCache = [pathOfCache stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"check.archive"];

    FeedChannel *channelCache = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:pathOfCache];


    if (!channelCachel) {
        channelCache = [[FeedChannel alloc] init];
    }
    FeedChannel *channelCopy = [channelCache copy];

    [connection setCompletionBlock:^(FeedChannel *obj, NSError *err) {
        if (!err) {
            [channelCopy addItemsFromChannel:obj];
            [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:channelCopy toFile:pathOfCache];
        }
        block(channelCopy, err);
    }];

    [connection setXmlObject:channel];
    [connection start];

    return channelCache;
}
```

and below are my encode and decode methods.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:link forKey:@"link"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:creator forKey:@"creator"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:pubDate forKey:@"pubDate"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:thumbnail forKey:@"thumbnail"];
    //[aCoder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail) forKey:@"thumbnail"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:publicationDate forKey:@"publicationDate"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setTitle:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"]];
        [self setLink:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"link"]];
        [self setCreator:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"creator"]];
        [self setPubDate:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"pubDate"]];
        [self setThumbnail:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbnail"]];
        //[self setThumbnail:[UIImage imageWithData:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];
        [self setPublicationDate:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"publicationDate"]];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Based on the answer, i don't know whether i have to use some extra code to persist images. because other objects like title, creator etc. are persisting accurately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading your comment, I tend to think that the issue has to do with how you persist the images relative to the dispatch_async block. I will try to explain, but this is just a guess, since I don't know where you persist the image:

1. at some point your `parser:foundCDATA:` is executed and you retrieve asynchronously your image;
2. the image will not be there for some time (until the sync block completes), so the `thumbnail` ivar/property will not have the right value for some time after completing `parser:foundCDATA:`;
3. now, if you persist `thumbnail` before the async block completes, you will persist the wrong (nil?) value;
4. the fact that if you do not execute the fetching of the image asynchronously, then everything works, makes me think that you are persisting the image *too early* (in the above sense).

The fix to this would be persisting the image only after the async block completes. This could mean something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

  NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSString *storyImageURL = [self getFirstImageUrl:someString];

  NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL URLWithString:storyImageURL];

  NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tempURL];
  thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:tempData];

  <code here to make the thumbnail be persisted>

});
```

`<code here to make the thumbnail be persisted>` could be a method call, a notification post, whatever fits your current design. You might also need to use the trick of dispatching the call to the main thread if your persistence code is not thread safe:

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      <persist thumbnail>;
  }
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

After our chat, the above analysis is confirmed. In fact, you are not simply downloading one image: you are downloading a bunch of images, all belonging to the same "channel". This means that the persist operation, which is applied to the whole channel, shall be executed only after all of those images have been downloaded.

I have thus forked your gist and added some logics enabling the use of GCD dispatch_group to keep track of all the download operations. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/4579906).

Comment: @Jessica: it took some time to get to the final version... hope it works for you.

Comment: I have tried both of your solutions, but the issue is same. When i use dispatch_asyc or dispatch_sych, the images stops persisting. The first time they loads but when i close and open the app, all other objects are there but not the images.

Comment: you have guessed everything right. Everything is happening exactly how you explained. I have used the code using main queue that you suggested in your updated answer but still it didn't work. Can you guess what else could be wrong. Thanks

Comment: well, I need to know how do you persist the image and especially where/when... your code only shows the assignment to the prop/ivar... actually, in my answer I suggested to stick/call the code to persist the image right after the assignment to the prop/ivar...

Comment: i have updated the code in the question. Kindly check it out.

Comment: thank you again. i have checked your updated answer. But as you said, my current design does not allow this as i have to keep the store and connection files separate and i haven't used NSNotificationCenter before and i have to solve this as soon as possible.

Comment: can you tell me how can i use some easy to use image caching library within my CDATA block where you mentioned i should persist images. SDImageCache library and its documentation mostly depicts that we should use it in the tableview controller.Although using library would be my last choice but i figured that i have to handle a lot of other things if i am not using a library like the first time it fetches images,it does not show the on screen images and i have to scroll it up and down when its starts showing the images.So can you kindly help me integrate it with a library in CDATA block

Comment: directly using `SDImageCache` does not seem to me as a big improvement, since you would need to handle on your own reading/writing from/into the cache and you would be pretty in the same situation as now; if you plan to use SDWebImage as a replacement for your thumbnail management, then it would do, but you should be aware that this requires using a `UIImageView` as opposed to `UIImage`. Could you change your thumbnail into a thumbnailView? btw, fuller code would help, at least interfaces for the store and parsing classes, otherwise it is pretty hard to figure out where things go...

Comment: in that case using SDImageCache would be a bad idea. Anyways i have updated the question with a gist link that contains parser and feed store code

Comment: thank you. could you briefly explain why you have channel and channelCopy? and why you pass channel into `setXmlRootObject:` and `channelCopy` into `archiveRootObject:`? `channelCopy` is not modified by the `connection` object...

Comment: i have updated this gist with the code that is handling the connection with the web service, that will explain the setXmlRootObject and channelCopy

Comment: sorry, but I cannot get to relate channelCopy with what happens inside TheConnection. Maybe it has to do with the block you pass to `fetchRSSFeedWithCompletion`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23055/discussion-between-jessica-and-sergio)

Comment: please check my gist: https://gist.github.com/4579906 and my last comment in chat...