# Multiple NSUrlRequests To Fetch Different Pages Of WebService To Load More Data In TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a simple iPhone app that is parsing data (titles, images etc.) from rss feed and showing in the tableview.

The viewDidLoad has an initial counter value to reach the first page of the feed and load in the tableview by calling the fetchEntriesNew method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    counter = 1;    
    [self fetchEntriesNew:counter];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(dataSaved:)
                                              name:@"DataSaved" object:nil];
}


- (void) fetchEntriesNew:(NSInteger )pageNumber
{    
    channel = [[TheFeedStore sharedStore] fetchWebService:pageNumber withCompletion:^(RSSChannel *obj, NSError *err){

            if (!err) {
                int currentItemCount = [[channel items] count];
                channel = obj;
                int newItemCount = [[channel items] count];
                NSLog(@"Total Number Of Entries Are: %d", newItemCount);
                counter = (newItemCount / 10) + 1;
                NSLog(@"New Counter Should Be %d", counter);


                int itemDelta = newItemCount - currentItemCount;
                if (itemDelta > 0) {

                    NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];

                    for (int i = 0; i < itemDelta; i++) {
                        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                        [rows addObject:ip];
                    }
                    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
                    [aiView stopAnimating];

                }
            }        
    }];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

When the user reaches the bottom of the tableview, i am using the following to reach the next page of the feed and load at the bottom of the first page that was loaded first:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        NSLog(@"Scroll End Called");
        NSLog(@"New Counter NOW is %d", counter);
        [self fetchEntriesNew:counter];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2:** Here is a more easy to understand description of whats wrong that i am unable to solve: For example there are 10 entries in the each page of the rss feed. The app starts, titles and other labels are loaded immediately and images starts loading lazily and finally gets finished. So far so good. The user scrolls to reach the bottom, reaching the bottom will use the scroll delegate method and the counter gets incremented from 1 to 2 telling the fetchEntriesNew method to reach the second page of the rss feed. The program will start loading the next 10 entries at the bottom of first 10 previously fetched. This can go on and the program will fetch 10 more entries every time the user scrolls and reaches bottom and the new rows will be placed below the previously fetched ones. So far so good.

Now let us say the user is on page 3 currently which has been loaded completely with the images. Since page 3 is loaded completely that means currently there are 30 entries in the tableview. The user now scrolls to the bottom, the counter gets incremented and the tableview begins populating the new rows from page 4 of the rss feed at the bottom of the first 30 entries. Titles get populated quickly thus building the rows and while the images are getting downloaded (not downloaded completely yet), the user quickly moves to the bottom again, instead of loading the 5th page at the bottom of the 4th, it will destroy the 4th ones that is currently in the middle of getting downloaded and starts loading the 4th one again.

What it should do is that it should keep on titles etc from next pages when user reaches the bottom of the tableview regardless of whether the images of the previous pages are in the middle of getting downloaded or not.

There is NO issue with the downloading and persisting data in my project and all the data is persisted between the application runs.

Can someone help to point me out to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 3:** Based on @Sergio's answer, this is what i did:

1) Added another call to archiveRootObject [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:channelCopy toFile:cachePath]; after         [channelCopy addItemsFromChannel:obj];

At this point, its not destroying and reloading the same batch again and again, exactly what i wanted. However, it doesn't persist images if i scroll multiple times to reach the next page without the images of the previous page were loaded completely.

2) I am not sure how to use Bool as he explained in the answer. This is what i did: Added @property Bool myBool; in TheFeedStore, synthesised it and set it to NO after newly added archiveRootObject:channelCopy and set it to YES in ListViewController at the very start of fetchEntries method. It didn't work.

3) I also realised the way i am dealing with the whole issue is performance vice not better. Although i don't know how to use images outside the cache and handle them as sort of cache. Are you suggesting to use a separate archiving file for images?

Thanks a lot to all people who have contributed in trying to solve my issue.

Comment: I'm confused. Why isn't the reloadData call INSIDE the callback? Also, do you really need it in the first place? The new rows will get cellForRowAtIndexPath called on them anyway...

Comment: That's strange. Might be because you're inserting rows at the beginning of the table, instead of the end?

Comment: excellent. I suppose that doesn't help you solve your problem, though... still, why are you inserting at the beginning of the table? can you put a log statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath and see which rows are being reloaded?

Comment: well, it seems you're inserting rows starting at index 0, which would be the first row of the table... anyway, it may be immaterial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue can be understood if you consider [this older question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388248/images-persistence-and-lazy-loading-conflict-with-dispatch-async) and [the solution I proposed](https://gist.github.com/4579906).

Specifically, the critical bit has to do with the way you are persisting the information (RSS info + images), which is through archiving your whole `channel` to a file on disk:

```
        [channelCopy addItemsFromChannel:obj];
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:channelCopy toFile:pathOfCache];
```

Now, if you look at `fetchEntriesNew:`, the first thing that you do there is destroying your current channel. If this happens **before the channel has been persisted to disk** you enter a sort of endless loop.

I understand you are currently persisting your channel (as per my original suggestion) at the very end of image download.

What you should do is persisting the channel just after the feed has been read and before starting downloading the images (you should of course also persist it at the end of image downloads).

So, if you take this snippet from my old gist:

```
[connection setCompletionBlock:^(RSSChannel *obj, NSError *err) {

    if (!err) {

        [channelCopy addItemsFromChannel:obj];

        // ADDED
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_group_wait(obj.imageDownloadGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
            [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:channelCopy toFile:cachePath];
        });
    }
    block(channelCopy, err);
```

what you should do is adding one more `archiveRootObject` call:

```
[connection setCompletionBlock:^(RSSChannel *obj, NSError *err) {

    if (!err) {

        [channelCopy addItemsFromChannel:obj];
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:channelCopy toFile:cachePath];

        // ADDED
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_group_wait(obj.imageDownloadGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
            [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:channelCopy toFile:cachePath];
        });
    }
    block(channelCopy, err);
```

This will make things work as long as you do not scroll fast enough so that the channel is destroyed before the feed (without images) is ever read. To fix this you should add a bool to your `TheFeedStore` class that you set to `YES` when you call `fetchWebService` and reset just after executing the newly added `archiveRootObject:channelCopy`.

This will fix your issues.

Let me also say that from a design/architecture point of view, you have a big issue with the way you manage persistence. Indeed, you have a single file on disk that you write atomically using `archiveRootObject`. This architecture is intrinsically "risky" from a multi-threading point of view and you should also devise a way to avoid that concurrent accesses to the shared stored have no destructive effects (e.g.: you archive your channel to disk for page 4 at the same time as the images for page 1 have been fully downloaded, hence you try to persist them as well to the same file).

Another approach to image handling would be storing the images outside of your archive file and treat them as a sort of cache. This would fix the concurrency issues and will also get rid of the performance penalty you get from archiving the channel twice for each page (when the feed is first read and later when the images have come in).

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

> At this point, its not destroying and reloading the same batch again and again, exactly what i wanted. However, it doesn't persist images if i scroll multiple times to reach the next page without the images of the previous page were loaded completely.

This is exactly what I meant saying that your architecture (shared archive/concurrent access) would probably lead to problems.

You have several options: use Core Data/sqlite; or, more easily, store each image in its own file. In the latter case, you could do following:

1. on retrieval, assign to each image a filename (this could be the id of the feed entry or a sequential number or whatever) and store the image data there;
2. store in the archive both the URL of the image and the filename where it should be stored;
3. when you need accessing the image, you don't get it from the archived dictionary directly; instead, you get the filename from the it then read the file from disk (if available);
4. this change would not affect otherwise your current implementation of rss/image retrieval, but only the way you persist the images and you access them when required (I mean, it seems a pretty easy change).

> 2) I am not sure how to use Bool as he explained in the answer.

1. add a `isDownloading` bool to TheFeedStore;
2. set it to `YES` in your `fetchWebService:` method, just before doing `[connection start]`;
3. set it to `NO` in the completion block you pass to the connection object (again in `fetchWebService:`) right after archiving the feed the first time (this you are already doing);
4. in your `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`, at the very beginning, do:

   ```
       if ([TheFeedStore sharedStore].isDownloading)
           return;
   ```

   so that you do not refresh the rss feed while a refresh is ongoing.

Let me know if this helps.

NEW UPDATE:

Let me sketch how you could deal with storing images in files.

In your RSSItem class, define:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIImage *thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *thumbFile;
```

`thumbFile` is the the path to the local file hosting the image. Once you have got the image URL (`getFirstImageUrl`), you can get, e.g., and MD5 hash of it and use this as your local image filename:

```
NSString* imageURLString = [self getFirstImageUrl:someString];
....
self.thumbFile = [imageURLString MD5String];
```

(MD5String is a category you can google for).

Then, in `downloadThumbnails`, you would store the image file locally:

```
    NSMutableData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalUrl];
    [tempData writeToFile:[self cachedFileURLFromFileName:self.thumbFile] atomically:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataSaved" object:nil];
```

Now, the trick is, when you access the `thumbnail` property, you read the image from file and return it:

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnail
{
    NSData* d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[self cachedFileURLFromFileName:self.thumbFile]];
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:d];
}
```

in this snippet, `cachedFileURLFromFileName:` is defined as:

```
- (NSURL*)cachedFileURLFromFileName:(NSString*)filename {

NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray *fileArray = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

NSURL* cacheURL = (NSURL*)[fileArray lastObject];
if(cacheURL)
{
    return [cacheURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}
return nil;
}
```

Of course, `thumbFile` should be persisted for this to work.

As you see, this approach is pretty "easy" to implement. This is not an optimized solution, just a quick way to make your app work with its current architecture.

For completeness, the `MD5String` category:

```
@interface NSString (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5String;

@end

@implementation NSString (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5String {
const char *cstr = [self UTF8String];
unsigned char result[16];
CC_MD5(cstr, strlen(cstr), result);

return [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
        result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
        result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
        ];  
}

@end
```

Comment: the bool has nothing to do with the images. it only prevents a feed page from being downloaded multiple times (imagine a slow connection and quick scroll down). for images, you only have core data or file cache...

Comment: Using Core Data would require rearchitecturing completely your app. Using Core Data only for the image files has no real meaning and no real advantage. Have a look at my sketchy implementation of the other approach I suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. in downloadThumbnails method, i have used writeToUrl instead of writeToFile, otherwise it shows a warning. Now no warning but program crashes with this "-[NSURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: component, components, or pathExtension cannot be nil.'
"

Comment: check `self.thumbFile` value. are you initializing it correctly before calling the method that crashes? I have suggested just one possible way to define `self.thumbFile` through an MD5 hash, but if you find tricky making this work, you could simply use a sequence counter (i.e., you name your file 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually trying to do, is implement paging in a `UITableView`

Now this is very straightforward and the best idea is to implement the paging in your `UITableView` delegate `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, instead of doing this on the `UIScrollView` `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` delegate method.

Here is my implementation of paging and I believe it should work perfectly for you too:

First of all, I have an implementation constants related to the paging:

```
//paging step size (how many items we get each time)
#define kPageStep 30
//auto paging offset (this means when we reach offset autopaging kicks in, i.e. 10 items before the end of list)
#define kPageBegin 10
```

The reason I'm doing this is to easily change the paging parameters on my .m file.

Here is how I do paging:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    int section = indexPath.section-1;

    while (section>=0) {
        row+= [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        section--;
    }

    if (row+kPageBegin>=currentItems && !isLoadingNewItems && currentItems+1<maxItems) {
        //begin request
        [self LoadMoreItems];
    }
......
}
```

- `currentItems` is an integer that has the number of the tableView datasource current items.
- `isLoadingNewItems` is a boolean that marks if items are being fetched at this moment, so we don't instantiate another request while we are loading the next batch from the server.
- `maxItems` is an integer that indicates when to stop paging, and is an value that I retrieve from our server and set it on my initial request.

You can omit the maxItems check if you don't want to have a limit.

and in my paging loading code I set the `isLoadingNewItems` flag to true and set it back to false after I retrieve the data from the server.

So in your situation this would look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    int section = indexPath.section-1;

    while (section>=0) {
        row+= [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        section--;
    }

    if (row+kPageBegin>=counter && !isDowloading) {
        //begin request
        isDowloading = YES;
        [self fetchEntriesNew:counter];
    }
......
}
```

Also there is no need to reload your whole table after adding the new rows.
Just use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemDelta; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [rows addObject:ip];
}

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: ah. i see your solution is more sophisticated just like instagram that starts loading next batch when the user is half the through the first batch. But my problem is different, check sergio's answer that currently i am testing

Answer (score 1):

A simple `BOOL` is enough to avoid repetitive calls:

```
BOOL isDowloading;
```

When the download is done, set it to `NO`. When it enters here:

```
 if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        NSLog(@"Scroll End Called");
        NSLog(@"New Counter NOW is %d", counter);
        [self fetchEntriesNew:counter];
    }
```

put it to `YES`. Also don't forget to set it to `NO` when the requests fails.

**Edit 1:**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        if(!isDowloading)
        {
           isDownloading = YES;
           NSLog(@"Scroll End Called");
           NSLog(@"New Counter NOW is %d", counter);
           [self fetchEntriesNew:counter];
        }
    }
}
```

And when you finish fetching, just set it to `NO` again.

Comment: No it won't. If you set it has `NO` in `viewDidLoad` for example, and `NO` when you actually finish the download (or failed) it would work)

Comment: i have done exactly what you said but it didn't work. Now i am starting to believe that issues lies somewhere else as the connection code is different while images are handled in a separate GCD independent of the connection methods. Your solution would have worked fine if the images weren't involved.

Comment: Where did you put the `isDownloading = NO` besides the `viewDidLoad`? Can you show me a gist with it?

Comment: check for "/////Tried here" comments in https://gist.github.com/jessicamoore112/5433625